# Is Indo-European Linguistics relevant or dead field?

Tags: historical-linguistics, indo-european

Sometimes I can hear from somebody that Indo-European linguistics is somewhat neglected. And instead, there some people who think that it is very important field. What can you say about this?

Comment: Where can I ask questions like this THEN?

Comment: It's definitely relevant though it shouldn't be overrated. It's probably better to study Indo-European linguistics together with something more specific (such as Romance or Slavonic linguistics).

Comment: IE linguistics is extremely relevant, and imho historical linguistics in general is the most interesting branch of linguistics  - but I might be biased. :) Something to consider: It is rather challenging to get a job in academia.

Comment: Alex, sounds encouraging! But why do you think so, that IE is extremely relevant?

Answer (score 1):

Indo-European is a field in which many scholars have been working for a very long time and which has to a certain extent ended up in a dead end, or perhaps rather in a fruitless impasse  (multi-laryngealists versus mono-laryngealists). If you want to make a big splash you might be better off researching a little-studied family such as Austroasiatic. It will not make you rich, but it might make you famous.

Comment: But how about career as a universitt teacher of İndo-European linguistics?

Comment: It is pointless to guess at the odds of success on such a narrow career path for a job opening that far in the future. Most universities do not have a position for an IE specialist so don't count on a timely retirement; many would be willing to hire a person who does general historical including IE and sociophonetics (or some similar unfocused job description). Check the CVs of all of the IE specialists that you can find; compare with those of all of the historical linguists.